# Undo git rm -r f (ambiguous argument 'HEAD') before first commit

Tags: git, git-reset, git-rm, git-fsck

I did a `git rm -r -f` on an ENTIRE directory in a new repo before I had ever committed. I had no branches.

I tried the answers on Stack Overflow, but none helped. I tried this:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

But got this:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

Is there any way I can get the files back?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you *can* salvage files.

The reason is that `git rm -r` will only remove files that are in the index, so for it to have removed stuff, you must have already `git add`-ed those files.  When you did that, git put a copy of the contents of each file into the repository, using the SHA-1 "true name" of the blob-contents.

If you now run `git fsck --lost-found`, git will find objects that have no reference (which is to say, all objects in the repository) and print `dangling <type> <SHA-1>`.  For each "blob" (in this case, everything it finds) it writes the contents into `.git/lost-found/other/` under the SHA-1 name:

```
$ git rm -r -f .
rm 'bar'
$ git fsck --lost-found
notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch (master)
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
notice: No default references
dangling blob f53433f357a56ddb698196519f30eb390ae684cb
$ cat .git/lost-found/other/f53433f357a56ddb698196519f30eb390ae684cb 
this is file bar
$
```

This also works for repositories that *do* have some commits and is a general method for "recovering stuff that used to have a reference, but no longer does".  This will find files you `git add`ed and then replaced with new, different contents that you `git add`ed "on top" of the old one before `git commit`ing.  It will also find any "abandoned" commits, including dropped git stashes.  (The commits go in `.git/lost-found/commit/`.)

In the above example, file `bar` conveniently claims to be file `bar` in its contents.  In most real cases you have to look at each recovered blob and guess at its original name.

Answer (score 0):

Since you deleted the data before you made any commits, you lost the data.

The `git reset --hard` doesn't work because you don't have an initial commit to reset back too.  Hence the 'ambiguous argument' error, git isn't able to figure out to which commit you are referring since there isn't one.

Comment: So, that's that? I'm screwed.

Comment: Short answer: yes. This should teach you the importance of making backup copies. If you really need that data, you _might_ have some luck with data-carving tools like Photorec.